# Definition of mean of a random variable in joint probability distribution?

Tags: probability

I am reading the "Probability & Statistics for Engineers & Scientists" 9th edition and encounter a proof of theorem 4.4 where it said:
$$\mu_{X}=\sum_{x}xf(x,y),\ \ \mu_{Y}=\sum_{y}yf(x,y)$$ where $f(x,y)$ is the joint probability distribution of the random variables X and Y . But as far as I'm aware, the mean of a random variable in a joint probability distribution should be: $$\mu_{X} = \sum_{x}x g(x) = \sum_{x} \sum_{y} x f(x, y) $$ where $g(x)$ is the marginal distributions of X alone $g(x) = \sum_{y}f(x,y)$.
Am i understanding this correctly or it is a mistake from the book ? Please help me clarify this.
Here is a link to the full proof in the book:[image]

Comment: The book is wrong.

Comment: To be precise: wherever that book says $\mu_{X}=\sum_{x}xf(x,y),\ \ \mu_{Y}=\sum_{y}yf(x,y)$ it is totally wrong. Your understanding about marginals is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly $\mu_X=\sum_xxf(x,y)$ cannot be right, because the RHS is a function of $y$.

As you say, it should be $\mu_X=\sum_x\sum_yxf(x,y)$. That is also clearly what the author meant, since that is what you need to substitute in the previous equation to get the final equation. So this appears to be a typesetting error.